# Create custom UIGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have create several custom UIGestureRecognizers without issue.  I decided I would like to have a custom version of single tap gesture and went about subclassing UIGestureRecognizer.  All seems fine except for one issue.  In my action handler [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self] always returns zero for both x and y.  When I go back to UITapGestureRecognizer the action handler works fine.  This must be something to do with the subclassed gesture recognizer, here is my code:

```
#import "gr_TapSingle.h"

#define tap_Timeout 0.25

@implementation gr_TapSingle


- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if ( self )
    {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)reset
{
}

-(void)gesture_Fail
{
    self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

    if ( [self numberOfTouches] > 1 )
    {
        self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed;
        return;
    }

    originLocation = [[[event allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:self.view];

    [self performSelector:@selector(gesture_Fail) withObject:nil afterDelay:tap_Timeout];
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];

    if ( self.state == UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible )
    {
        CGPoint l_Location = [[[event allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
        CGPoint l_Location_Delta = CGPointMake( l_Location.x - originLocation.x, l_Location.y - originLocation.y );
        CGFloat l_Distance_Delta = sqrt( l_Location_Delta.x * l_Location_Delta.x + l_Location_Delta.y * l_Location_Delta.y );
        if ( l_Distance_Delta > 15 )
            self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed;
        return;
    }
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];

    if ( self.state == UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible )
        [[self class] cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(gesture_Fail) object:nil];

    if ( self.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed )
        self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded;
}

-(void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    [super touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];
    if ( self.state == UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible )
        [[self class] cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(gesture_Fail) object:nil];
    self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple's docs say:

> The returned value is a generic single-point location for the gesture
>   computed by the UIKit framework. It is usually the centroid of the
>   touches involved in the gesture. For objects of the
>   UISwipeGestureRecognizer and UITapGestureRecognizer classes, the
>   location returned by this method has a significance special to the
>   gesture. This significance is documented in the reference for those
>   classes.

So I assume every subclass has it's own special implementation of this method, fitting its own specialties. So you have to implement this on your own if you want to subclass `UIGestureRecognizer`.

EDIT:

Something like:

```
- (CGPoint)locationInView:(UIView *)view
{
   if(view == self.view)
   {
      return originLocation;
   }
   else
   {
     //you decide
   }
}
```